# Using AJAX to send a checkbox value

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, var

I have an ajax script that sends data. I only want it to send the data if the input is checked. for each input i have defined a specific value. How can i only have the data input defined if it is checked? or is there a better (simple) way to do it? All of this is within a dialog.

```
            "Send": (function() {
                        var data = {
                            name: $("input#name").val(),
                            phone: $("input#phone").val(),
                            email: $("input#email").val(),
                            interest1: $("input#interest1").val(),
                            interest2: $("input#interest2").val(),
                            interest3: $("input#interest3").val(),
                            yesA: $("input#yesA").val(),
                            noA: $("input#noA").val(),
                            yesB: $("input#yesB").val(),
                            noB: $("input#noB").val(),
                            interest_1:
                                if("input#interest_1").is(':checked')) {
                                    $("input#interest_1").val(),
                                }
                            interest_2: $("input#interest_2").val(),
                            interest_3: $("input#interest_3").val(),
                            architectY: $("input#architectY").val(),
                            architectN: $("input#architectN").val(),
                            plansY: $("input#plansY").val(),
                            plansN: $("input#plansN").val(),
                            datepicker: $("input#datepicker").val(),
                            alt_date: $("input#alt_date").val(),
                        }
                        var $dialog=$(this)
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "mailer.php",
                            data: data,
                            success: function () {
                                $dialog.dialog("close");
                            }
                        });
                        return false;  


                              }),
```

An abeviated version of the form looks like this: note* i do not want to use radio buttons because users should be able to choose multiple options.

```
     <div id="dialog">
      <form method="post" action="mailer.php">
       <input type="checkbox" id="interest_1" value="option A"/>Option A
       <input type="checkbox" id="interest_2" value="option B"/>Option B
       <input type="checkbox" id="interest_3" value="option C"/>Option C
     </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: You could use an `if` statement

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: I am trying to use an i statement but i isnt working. 

Also i updated my question with an abreviated version of the form. the html is correct, i am sure about that. I just want the value of each of the options to be assigned to the data and sent to my mailer.php if the box is checked

Comment: You could use `$('form').serialize()` to generate the data.

Comment: @Daiwei what would that do to my checkbox values? how would it compute the inputs?

Comment: @TylerRichardson yes, it will calculate value for check box, if the box is not checked, value is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question's a little vague, but I assume your problem is with this:

```
interest_1:
    if("input#interest_1").is(':checked')) {
        $("input#interest_1").val(),
    }
```

So, if I understand this correctly, you want if `input#interest_1` is checked, set `interest_1` in your ajax data. In that case, you can use an *immediately invoked function expression* (IIFE) like this:

```
interest_1: (function() { 
    if($("input#interest_1").is(":checked")) {
        return $("input#interest_1").val();
    }
})(),
```

Now if `interest_1` is checked, then the function will return its `.val()`. Otherwise it will be void.